# How to setup the Http GET request with multple slashes in postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, webapi

I have an API request like this
"https://host/Tradings/Transactions/Speciality/1"

And in C# code TradingsController it is like.

```
[HttpGet("Transactions/Speciality/{id}")]
```

The API is all good. But when I set up this request with Id as key in Postman with :
{{host}}/Tradings/Transactions/Speciality/?id=1

The response was an error with details as below.

```
{
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
"title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
"status": 400,
"traceId": "00-9b838f0ccd00e673ec97734bc8cc0faf-eeed59634218860d-00",
"errors": {
    "id": [
        "The value 'Speciality' is not valid."
    ]
}
```

}

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It seems likely that you're matching a different route (i.e. `Transaction/{something}`) because `{id}` is a route parameter, not a query parameter. `?` in a URL denotes the start of query parameters. Which do you want?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Yes. I put {{host}}/Tradings/Transactions/Speciality/ in the url and then add id as a key in Params. I thought it should be matching "Transactions/Speciality/{id}" ?

Comment: Params in Postman modifies the query string, it doesn't modify the URL itself (i.e. the route). I think that's where you're going wrong.

Comment: should be {{host}}/Tradings/Transactions/Speciality/1 and check if you are doing any model validation on that field as it will throw back that sort of error.